# Connection between CI and simple php for to read $_SESSION

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to integrate a forum (created in Codeigniter) into a website (simple php >>> no framework used).

In order to automatically login to the forum, when I login in my website, I need to use a function of the forum which expects 2 parameters $username and $password.

I already have this informations (username and password) from my website, in $_SESSION.

How can I read the $_SESSION from the forum(as I say before Codeigniter based), because, I have no acces to it.

Is there a posibility to define 2 constants, somewhere in the core / config of the forum, to hold these details from $_SESSION, in order to have acces from anywhere inside the forum ?

I know that the sessions from CI are different from $_SESSION, so please help me with something more practical, in order to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the location of the CI site fall within the scope of the cookie holding the session identifier? AFAIK CI session are separate from PHP sessions, so you should be able to safely call `session_start()` in a CI page and it will work like it does everywhere else.

Comment: Yeap, this is the correct answer for me :) I always have this problem, because I work with frameworks, which autoload these classes :( Thanks and +1

Answer (score 1):

Read this url;-

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/158923/#766011

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/188648/#892137

In case for those who want to do native session with 2.0.2

Just copy the native_session.php file to your application/libraries/ and rename it as Session.php

Then change the class name and constructor name to CI_Session

Also add the following then it should work fine.

```
function sess_destroy()
{
  $this->destroy();
}
```

or

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
    Native / Database hybrid
    Code Igniter
    Citrusmedia - Matthew Lymer
*/


class CI_Session
{
    var $sess_table_name            = '';
    var $sess_expiration            = 7200;
    var $sess_match_ip                = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_useragent        = TRUE;
    var $sess_time_to_update        = 300;
    var $encryption_key                = '';
    var $flashdata_key                 = 'flash';
    var $time_reference                = 'time';
    var $gc_probability                = 5;
    var $userdata                    = array();
    var $CI;
    var $now;

    /**
     * Session Constructor
     *
     * The constructor runs the session routines automatically
     * whenever the class is instantiated.
     */
    function CI_Session($params = array())
    {                
        log_message('debug', "Session Class Initialized");

        // Set the super object to a local variable for use throughout the class
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        // Set all the session preferences, which can either be set
        // manually via the $params array above or via the config file
        foreach (array('sess_table_name', 'sess_expiration', 'sess_match_ip', 'sess_match_useragent', 'sess_time_to_update', 'time_reference', 'encryption_key') as $key)
        {
            $this->$key = (isset($params[$key])) ? $params[$key] : $this->CI->config->item($key);
        }

        // Sessions, start your engines!
        ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $this->sess_expiration);
        session_start();

        // Load the string helper so we can use the strip_slashes() function
        $this->CI->load->helper('string');

        // Are we using a database?  If so, load it
        if( !$this->sess_table_name ) {
            die('Session class database table name not configured');
        }

        $this->CI->load->database();

        // Set the "now" time.  Can either be GMT or server time, based on the
        // config prefs.  We use this to set the "last activity" time
        $this->now = $this->_get_time();

        // Set the session length. If the session expiration is
        // set to zero we'll set the expiration two years from now.
        if ($this->sess_expiration == 0)
        {
            $this->sess_expiration = (60*60*24*365*2);
        }

        // Run the Session routine. If a session doesn't exist we'll
        // create a new one.  If it does, we'll update it.
        if ( ! $this->sess_read())
        {
            $this->sess_create();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->sess_update();
        }

        // Delete 'old' flashdata (from last request)
           $this->_flashdata_sweep();

        // Mark all new flashdata as old (data will be deleted before next request)
           $this->_flashdata_mark();

        // Delete expired sessions if necessary
        $this->_sess_gc();

        log_message('debug', "Session routines successfully run");
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Fetch the current session data if it exists
     *
     * @access    public
     * @return    bool
     */
    function sess_read()
    {
        // Unserialize the session array
        // $session = $this->_unserialize($session);

        $session = array();

        foreach( array('session_id', 'ip_address', 'user_agent', 'last_activity') as $key )
        {
            if( !isset($_SESSION[$key]) ) {
                $this->sess_destroy();
                return FALSE;
            }

            $session[$key] = $_SESSION[$key];
        }    

        // Is the session current?
        if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Does the IP Match?
        if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE AND $session['ip_address'] != $this->CI->input->ip_address())
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Does the User Agent Match?
        if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE AND trim($session['user_agent']) != trim(substr($this->CI->input->user_agent(), 0, 50)))
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $session['session_id']);

        if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('ip_address', $session['ip_address']);
        }

        if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('user_agent', $session['user_agent']);
        }

        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);
```

Comment: `Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions.`

Comment: if you want $_SESSION variable then you want to session_start(); in Authentication file

Comment: As I already wrote in my message : " I know that the sessions from CI are different from $_SESSION, so please help me with something more practical, in order to solve my problem."